# How to create menu from UITableView, with unknown number of sub-menus?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

**How to display a multi-level menu as a `UITableView` in Swift**

I'm trying to display a multi-level menu as a series of `UITableView`s, where each object may have an unknown number of children, which then may have *n* number of children, and so on.

I'm currently attempting to get it to work with a closure callback (below), but running into problems once I'm two-levels deep into the menu hierarchy.

The relevant code:

**TableViewController**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var selectedObject:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    if (self.hasChildren) {
       selectedObject  = self.childrenObjects![indexPath.row]
    } else {
        selectedObject = self.tableViewData![indexPath.row]
    }


    self.selectionCallback!(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath, selectedObject: selectedObject, doesHaveChildren: self.hasChildren)
}
```

**MenuViewController**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let menuTableViewController:TableViewBuilder = TableViewBuilder()
    menuTableViewController.tableViewData = self.passedData as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>?

    self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuTableViewController)


    self.presentViewController(self.navController!, animated: false) {
        print("Nav controller presented")
        //navController.pushViewController(menuTableViewController, animated: false)
    }

    self.selectedTapCallback = { (tableView, indexPath, selectedObject, doesHaveChildrenTop) in

        let detailMenuViewController:TableViewBuilder = TableViewBuilder()
        detailMenuViewController.tableViewData = selectedObject["children"] as! StandardCollectionType
        self.navController!.pushViewController(detailMenuViewController, animated: true)
    }



    menuTableViewController.setSelectedCallback(self.selectedTapCallback!)


}
```

**The data that I'm trying to represent is as follows:**

```
    "menu": [
                    {
                        "title": "Jurisdiction",
                        "subtitle": "Where did you get the ticket?",
                        "has_children": true,
                        "meta": {
                            "top_level_menu": true
                        },

                        "children": [{
                            "title": "New South Wales",
                            "subtitle": "Seeking review with the Office of State Revenue (SDRO)",
                            "has_children": true,
                            "meta": {
                                "option_uid": "nsw"
                            },

                            "children": [{
                                    "title": "Car registration permit date inccorect",
                                    "subtitle": null,
                                    "has_children": false,
                                    "meta": {
                                        "option_uid": "nsw.permit.date.inccorect"
                                    }
                                },

                                {
                                    "title": "There was an issue with the signs",
                                    "subtitle": "This could be due to a number of reasons",
                                    "has_children": true,
                                    "children": [{
                                            "title": "The signs were contradictory",
                                            "subtitle": null,
                                            "has_children": false,
                                            "meta": {
                                                "option_uid": "nsw.bay.signs.contradictory"
                                            }
                                        },

                                        {
                                            "title": "The signs were unclear",
                                            "subtitle": "The signs may have been unclear or ambiguous",
                                            "has_children": false,
                                            "meta": {
                                                "option_uid": "nsw.bay.signs.unclear"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },

                                {
                                    "title": "The offence happened after I sold the car",
                                    "subtitle": "It wasn't me!",
                                    "has_children": false,
                                    "meta": {
                                        "option_uid": "nsw.car.after.sold"
                                    }
                                }
```

I'm trying to handle presenting this by using a closure callback triggered by `- tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` to instantiate another `MenuViewController` instance (as in code above), and then get the main navigation controller to push it, but this is breaking when trying to move to a third level of the menu from the second level.

Any ideas as to the best way to handle this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I developed something similar and I used this [library](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController).

Hope that this can help you.